# I m trying to move the recurring total before the Total in woocomerce subscription

Tags: woocommerce-subscriptions

I m trying to move the position of recurring total before the Total in woocomerce cart and checkout page

Can we shift the position of recurring total before the Total in checkout page in woocomerce subscription
[![enter image description here]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV2jM.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pV2jM.jpg)